# Specify directories to not be removed on uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX installer for an app that can generate two folders while running. I'd like these two folders to not be removed on uninstall however. I'm using `RemoveFolderEx` to remove the entire install directory, but wasn't sure if there was a way to exclude folders from being removed.

I've tried using a Custom Action with a PowerShell script to move the folders out of the directory, but this solution would rely on the script being somewhere outside of the install directory in order to be run before the folders are removed, and doing this unfortunately gets rid of the installer's portability.

Comment: Where are these folders located? You should not write to folders that are under Program Files. Are they in the user profile? Typically you would generate folders you want to keep on application launch in the user-profile. The setup will then not know anything about the folders and leave them alone.

Comment: _"I'm using RemoveFolderEx to remove the entire install directory"_ -- why? Windows Installer automatically removes files that were installed before. You don't need to do anything for that. All other files you should not touch, because they may be user data (although users are not supposed to store files in the installation directory, it happens).

Comment: The need for cleanup is often misunderstood I think. You can not safely or reliably delete userprofile files for all users with normal setup means. I guess you might want to add your application to the cleanup manager `cleanmgr.exe` instead? I haven't seen it done. Just if you insist on cleaning up files although user profile files are basically user data and shouldn't be handled automatically since you don't know what the user wants to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the msidbComponentAttributesPermanent attribute on the required Component(s) to make them permanent?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/component-table